# How can I create an Array from mySQL database?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM people WHERE id = '$id'";  
$array = array();       
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
$array[] = $row;
}
```

My result is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "fred"
    [0]=>
    string(4) "fred"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "sam"
    [0]=>
    string(3) "sam"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "alan"
    [0]=>
    string(4) "alan"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(63) "john"
    [0]=>
    string(63) "john"
  }
}
```

But I would need:

```
Array
(
    [fred] => fred
    [sam] => sam
    [alan] => alan
    [john] => john
)
```

I tried for example:

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $key => $row) {..
```

and also

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
$array[] = $row;
$row = array_combine(array_values($row), array_values($row));
}
```

but I always get the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use fetchAll()**

But not a vanilla one but with a secret argument called [PDO::FETCH_COLUMN](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#column)

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM people WHERE id = ?";  
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute([$id]);
$array = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

It will get you a single-dimensional array with names like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => fred
    [1] => sam
    [2] => alan
    [3] => john
)
```

> Note that you are using prepared statements **completely wrong way** making your code vulnerable to SQL injection. It is fixed in the code above.

If you insists on getting both key and value, then change your code as follows

```
$sql = "SELECT name, name FROM people WHERE id = ?";  
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute([$id]);
$array = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

and it will give you exact array as you asked

Comment: Out of curiosuty, which one you choose? By the way, there are other magic modes in PDO, worth a quick glance. May be I should make a cheatsheet...

Comment: I was choosing the second solution. Could you tell me why my statements are insecure?

Comment: Because you are adding variables directly to the query, which makes it vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

Use **[fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)**

```
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
$result = $q->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Also you have to specify fetch mode.

Comment: Thank you! :) Does this method has some advantages to Ashwanis suggestion, or is it up to personal taste which method to choose

Comment: This in in build function of PDO you can direct get your desier result without use of any loop

Comment: @fusion3k in that case no use of any mode

Comment: `fetchAll()` in itself employs a loop.

Comment: OK, I see now that OP wants values as keys.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes:

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $array[$row['name']] = $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Great! Working very well :o)

Comment: I am glad that it helped, I would seek your approval/acceptance to my answer :-)

Comment: @Jarla please approve the answer so that people can rely over it.